# Oracle SQL table and index statistics

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I've been doing some reading on gathering table and index statistics on Oracle databases but it's left me ... confused.

For the sake of argument, let's assume Oracle 11gR2 as the RDBMS. Regarding gathering table and index statistics, when should it be done, which is the preferred way of doing it, and does Oracle really automatically gather the necessary statistics for us?

Regarding the first point: when should it be done. I've read that, as a rule of thumb, gathering table and index statistics should be done after around 10% of the table's records have been modified (inserted, updated, etc) since the last time the table was analyzed.

Regarding the second point: which is the preferred way of doing it. If we want to calculate both table and index statistics, does executing DBMS_STATS.GATHER_TABLE_STATS with default options, assuming the table is not partitioned, suffice?

Regarding the third point:does Oracle really gather the necessary statistics automatically for us. If this is the case, should i not worry abouth gathering table statistics (see points 1 and 2)?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:** Following the comment by [ammoQ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/65464/ammoq), i realized that the question is not clear in what the use case really is, here. My question is about tables that aren' "manipulated" via a user's actions, i.e manually, rather via procedures typically ran by database jobs. Take my example, for instance. My ETL process loads several tables on a daily basis and it does so in approximately 1 hour. Of that 1 hour, about half is spent analyzing the tables themselves. Thus, the tables area analyzed daily, following insertions or updates. This seems overkill, hence the question.

Comment: when should it be done: At bare minimum, when you notice that the query optimizer chooses bad plans. ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I've clarified the question.

Comment: gather table stats autotasks: https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1133388300346992024

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, you need to have statistics that are representative (not necessarily accurate) and that give you the right execution plan. By default, Oracle will run a statistics collection job, during the nightly batch window. That may be fine for some applications, but if you have a data warehouse, which presumably includes a regular data load process, then managing the stats should be part of that process. Note that I have said "managing" and not "collecting" statistics. That's just my way of saying that there are other options for statistics in addition to just gathering statistics, although gathering statistics would be where I would start.
There are also things that can be done to optimize statistics gathering, incremental statistics for example. The other thing that is *very* important is is to use the AUTO Sample size when gathering stats. Do not specify a percentage, not even 100%. The reason is that auto sample size enables a number of internal optimizations and capabilities that are disabled if you do not use AUTO sample size.

So, taking your specific points

1. 10% staleness is pretty random, and is just a number used by the auto stats.
2. dbms_stats.gather_table_stats() with default values *is* the preferred method. One parameter that I may change would be the DEGREE, to enable stats gathering in parallel
3. In 12c, *basic* stats are gathered on load into an empty table (or empty partition). Stats are built on indexes when indexes are created. So to reiterate what I said above, stats gathering should be part of your ELT process.

I hope that makes sense and helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, @BobC. What bothers me the most is that gathering statistics is the most time consuming bit of my ETL process. Like i said in the last edit of my original post, about half the time consumed by the ETL process itself is spent on gathering statistics. This is especially true with the largest tables with (tens of) millions of rows. I'll try different levels of DEGREE to see if i can squeeze out any precious seconds or minutes.

Comment: @DylanW80 What hardware do you have? ie how many CPU cores and how much (observed) IO bandwidth do you have? I would not just gather stats on indexed columns; you need stats on everything. Are you loading into an empty table or is it already populated? Is your 10M row table partitioned?

Comment: Unfortunately i don't really know the details of the hardware the database sits on. I only know, from experience, that it is relatively "fast". The table is already populated. Everyday i insert the data from the day before. The table is not partitioned. I've tried doing this but i don't really have a partition "key"/"strategy" (if it makes sense)

Comment: Define "relatively fast". Can you describe your table (in business terms)? If it does not have a natural partition key, such as something that would make the queries faster via partition pruning, then you could introduce a LOAD_KEY column and partition on that. Then you can employ things like partition exchange and incremental stats. With your table not being partitioned, you stats gathering is going to get longer and longer as the size of the table increases. If your table is partitioned, you only have to gather stats on the newly loaded data. This is called INCREMENTAL stats.

Comment: Recently i had to update 3 million rows in one of the tables with tens of millions of rows i mentioned before and it took under 2 minutes (standard update). I honestly don't know if this is enough to establish a quick benchmark, but it's what i can remember off the top of my head. I have never heard of LOAD_KEY columns. I've tried googling to no avail. Do you have more info or some literature on that?

Comment: LOAD_KEY is my term ;)  What I mean is just a new column to uniquely identify  a "data load". If you load once a day, it could be a LOAD_DATE. It would not have any real business function, but just a means to partition. This is assuming that your assertion that you have not other way of partitioning is correct.

Comment: Regarding the business side of things, this specific table holds customer information (name, age, telephone, etc).

Comment: So each day, you are loading a bunch of new customers?

Comment: I kind of figured that was what you meant by LOAD_KEY. The uppercase, underscore threw me off a bit. Plus, english is not my mother tongue.

Comment: Each day i load new customers or update the details about existing customers.

Comment: Ah. What is you native language? I will attempt to be more verbose in future.

Comment: My native language is Portuguese

Comment: If you are doing updates too, then a LOAD_KEY will probably not work. Whats your ratio of inserts to updates?

Comment: Around 60 to 40, but it may vary,